# Find the sum of $n$ terms of the series $\frac{1}{1\cdot5}+\frac{1}{3\cdot7}+\frac{1}{5\cdot9}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the sum of $n$ terms of the series  $$\frac{1}{1\cdot5}+\frac{1}{3\cdot7}+\frac{1}{5\cdot9}+\dots$$

My attempt  : $$T_{n}= \frac{1}{4}[\frac{1}{2n-1}]-\frac{1}{4}[\frac{1}{2n+3}]$$

I am not sure how to proceed next.

Kindly explain the process and comment on techniques to solve other problems of such pattern.

Source: Barnard and Child Higher Algebra Exercise XIV-B Q.7

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+3)}&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+3}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=3}^{n+2}\frac{1}{2k-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}}_{=0}-\frac{1}{4(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{4(2n+3)}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{4(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{4(2n+3)}
\end{align*}